# Read contents of an embed message from a discord server

Tags: javascript, discord

**Scenario**:
I am trying to **read** various fields in an embed message posted to a sever, do some processing, and log results in a DB.

**Testing**:
Using a testBot for sending relevant messages everything works when using a normal text message, but when an "embed message" is used (theoretically making it much easier to identify fields for processing etc), I can't retrieve the data.  I'm at an total loss how to access the "embed" from the message object.

I realize that it is about now I should pop in some code for you to examine, but I'm not even that far along !  Reading the documentation (linked to at the end) I am pretty sure is will be something to do with one of these classes:-
message.**embeds**.x.y.z   or  **MessageEmbed.x.y.x**

Google has not been my friend, I can not find one example of code that reads an "Embed message" which is odd.

Anyway, to ensure I don't look like a complete sponge I'll include the working code for the "embed sender bot".   A few people seem to have problems cracking the syntax, so it maybe of use to someone else searching on here...

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

**Documentation Found**:
[Docs for MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)
And;

[Embed used within message class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage)

**Code for test Embed sender bot:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");
  const client = new Discord.Client();
  const config = require("./config.json");

  /* A simple bot to throw out a test "Embed message" when asked to. */

  client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) 
  return;

   if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "emb")) {
   console.log("Sending an embedd message");
   message.channel.send({embed: {
    color: 3447003,
    title: "This is an embed (Title)",
    description: "Embed! (first line)\nsecond line of Desc\nthird line of 
   Desc",
    footer: 
    {
        text: "Footnote ©"
    }
  }});
} else   if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "test")) 
  {
  message.reply("Bot active");


  };

 });

  client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have your `Message` object, check the `embeds` property to obtain an array of all `MessageEmbeds` contained inside it. You can then read any of the properties, such as `description`, `fields`, etc.

Here's some example code:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
/* client.login, etc. etc. */

client.on('message', (msg) => {
    msg.embeds.forEach((embed) => {
       // add this embed to the database, using embed.description, embed.fields, etc.
        // if there are no embeds, this code won't run.
    });
    msg.reply("Embed sent!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Techo.
I had managed to stumble on the correct syntax (more luck than anything!)  And of course after you get the first bit, the rest falls into place.

knowing that I would only ever receive on embed within a single message I ended up with this as the test:-
`try {(message.embeds[0].description);} catch(err){return}; //work on only Embeds `
Your's is a better more rounded and general answer ;-)
Thanks again.

Comment: Did try to give you an upvote, but apparently am too new to the site for it to show up ;-)   Hope it registered