# Accessing Properties of MessageEmbed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to access the ***description*** of this Message embed, but it'll only let me go as far as `console.log(reaction.message.embeds)`, which then gives me the block you see below

if I try to enter: `console.log(reaction.message.embeds.MessageEmbed.description)`
My console reads: ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined***

Im assuming this is because i'm calling it incorrectly, but I don't know any other way to call the property...

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you for reading...

```
[ MessageEmbed {
message: 
 Message {
   channel: [TextChannel],
   deleted: false,
   id: '508770239903825922',
   type: 'DEFAULT',
   content: '',
   author: [ClientUser],
   member: [GuildMember],
   pinned: false,
   tts: false,
   nonce: null,
   system: false,
   embeds: [Circular],
   attachments: Collection {},
   createdTimestamp: 1541370677687,
   editedTimestamp: null,
   reactions: [Collection],
   mentions: [MessageMentions],
   webhookID: null,
   hit: null,
   _edits: [Array] },
type: 'rich',
title: 'Canny Valley ',
description: 'User: <@239449569677672448>',
url: undefined,
color: 3447003,
fields: [],
timestamp: undefined,
thumbnail: null,
image: null,
video: null,
author: null,
provider: null,
footer: null } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just wanted to post this here just in case someone in the future has the same issue as me...

[Read contents of an embed message from a discord server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073719/read-contents-of-an-embed-message-from-a-discord-server)

This helped me a lot, took quite a bit of searching though!

The solution would be: `reaction.message.embeds[0].description` giving me the exact value that I needed!