# Discord.js - How to copy a portion of an other bot's embed

Tags: discord.js, embed

I want to copy some text information displayed on an embed of another bot, and then post that information from my bot. I am completely stuck on how to do this. How would I?

Comment: Have you tried doing research and checking out the DJS guide and or Documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    message.embeds.forEach(embed => {
        //You can resend the embed whole or some parts of it
        //If you want to resend the whole embed
        message.channel.send(embed);
        //Or, some parts of it
        let description = embed.description;
        let title = embed.title;
        if(title && description){
            let emb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(title)
                .setDescription(description)
            message.channel.send(emb);
        }
    });
});
```

Also check this out [Read contents of an embed message from a discord server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073719/read-contents-of-an-embed-message-from-a-discord-server)